# Android: Sliding between tabs (not the tab content)

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe

I used ViewPager and PagerTitleStrip to make the swipe effect between tabs' content. Everything works fine. But now I would like to make the tabs scrollable themselves independent from the content of the tab like the Android play store.

What would be an approach for this feature?

Thank you :).

Comment: I am not sure about the libraries you are using but, generally speaking, add your titles to a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib: Thanks for your hint. I have just tried that solution but i got an excpetion that PagerTitleStrip must be a direct child of a ViewPager. Perhaps I could add my PagerTabStrip in another ViewPager?

Comment: I just googled this PageTitleStrip and I honestly did not know about. It seems to me this will be doable using it: You might have to use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator library available here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution around this ? Thanks.

Comment: @JabbarJigariyo, too bad i haven't found any solution with does not involve third party libraries :(. So for now i just use the standard ViewPager of Google.